# Mapfish-Print with SLD Style and TTF marks

Tags: geoserver, sld, mapfish-print-2, ttf

Is it possible to print ttf's in an SLD using mapfish-print?

```
<GraphicFill>
    <Graphic>
        <Opacity>1</Opacity>
        <Size>25</Size>
        <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>ttf://my_font#32</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#1F1FCD</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
                <CssParameter name="stroke">#1F1FCD</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
        </Mark>
    </Graphic>
</GraphicFill>
```

This is how it works on Geoserver already. In mapfish it works with Shape symbols like `shape://slash` but not with the Bulk TTF marks. How could it do this?

---

**Versions**

- Mapfish 3.10.2
- Geoserver: 2.14.0
- Geotools: 20.0

**Log**

```
Request: getServiceInfo
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverter: Converting object of class java.lang.String to org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,790 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 13
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 13
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
--- following part 4x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:05,791 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - StyleImpl added 13 feature types
--- following part 7x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
--- following part 8x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Computed scale denominator: 49999.99999999999
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 1
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - creating rules for scale denominator - 50'000
--- following part 7x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,792 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
--- following part 8x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Processing 1 stylers for http://myApp:layer_name_1
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Querying layer http://myApp:layer_name_1 with bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[2727972.0000000005 : 2728308.0000000005, 1270452.0000000002 : 1270788.0000000002]
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2019-03-08 22:31:05,793 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting LogicFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting NullFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting LogicFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting SQL ComparisonFilter
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.filter] - exporting PropertyName
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT someSqlStuff
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 1 = POLYGON ((2727972.0000000005 1270452.0000000002, 2727972.0000000005 1270788.0000000002, 2728308.0000000005 1270788.0000000002, 2728308.0000000005 1270452.0000000002, 2727972.0000000005 1270452.0000000002))
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 2 = myApp
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 3 = CH
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 4 = 744
2019-03-08 22:31:05,794 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - 5 = 1035
2019-03-08 22:31:05,802 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2019-03-08 22:31:05,802 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.label] - TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
2019-03-08 22:31:05,802 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.label] - PAINTED LINE LABELS : 0
2019-03-08 22:31:05,802 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.label] - REMAINING LINE LABELS : 0
2019-03-08 22:31:05,802 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Style cache hit ratio: NaN , hits 0, requests 0
2019-03-08 22:31:05,802 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
Request: getFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = http://myByUrl:80/
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    FeatureCount = 20
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest =
GetMap Request
 version: 1.3.0
 output format: image/png
 width height: 512,512
 bbox: SRSEnvelope[2721056.0 : 2728224.0, 1263984.0 : 1271152.0]
 layers: myApp:layer_name_1
 styles: style_213
    InfoFormat = application/json
    PropertyNames = [[name1, name2, name3, name4, ...]]
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@d87fb7ef]
    RawKvp = ...
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.3.0
    XPixel = 506
    YPixel = 38
2019-03-08 22:31:05,803 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2019-03-08 22:31:06,161 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverter: Converting object of class java.lang.String to org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:06,162 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 29
2019-03-08 22:31:06,163 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - number of fts set 29
2019-03-08 22:31:06,163 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
--- following part 27x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:06,163 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2019-03-08 22:31:06,163 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:06,163 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:06,164 TRACE [org.geotools.styling] - ENTRY
2019-03-08 22:31:06,164 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - creating defaultMark
2019-03-08 22:31:06,164 DEBUG [org.geotools.styling] - StyleImpl added 29 feature types
2019-03-08 22:31:06,164 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
Request: getFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = http://myByUrl:80/
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    FeatureCount = 20
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest =
GetMap Request
 version: 1.3.0
 output format: image/png
 width height: 512,512
 bbox: SRSEnvelope[2721056.0 : 2728224.0, 1263984.0 : 1271152.0]
 layers: myApp:layer_name_1
 styles: style_148-286
    InfoFormat = application/json
    PropertyNames = [[name1, name2, name3, name4, ...]]
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@558cdfe9]
    RawKvp = ...
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.3.0
    XPixel = 506
    YPixel = 38
2019-03-08 22:31:06,164 INFO [org.geoserver.wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
2019-03-08 22:31:10,326 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
2019-03-08 22:31:10,326 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo
2019-03-08 22:31:10,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,327 DEBUG [org.geotools.util] - InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation  only.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (GridCoverageFactory)
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (GridCoverageFactory): found implementation Optional.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Rendering using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationBilinear@3a9af610
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (GridCoverageFactory)
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Rendering using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationBilinear@3a9af610
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (GridCoverageFactory): found implementation Optional.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Rendering using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationBilinear@3a9af610
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Rendering using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationBilinear@3a9af610
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Rendering using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationBilinear@3a9af610
2019-03-08 22:31:10,329 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Rendering using interpolation javax.media.jai.InterpolationBilinear@3a9af610
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.index.quadtree] - QuadTree opened
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adjusted Requested Envelope = ReferencedEnvelope[2749970.5 : 2750040.5, 1242959.5 : 1243029.5]
Requested raster dimension = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=70,height=70]
Corresponding raster source region = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=70,height=70]
Corresponding source Envelope = ReferencedEnvelope[2749970.5 : 2750040.5, 1242959.5 : 1243029.5]
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Empty results for 2, skipping read
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Loading level 0 with subsampling factors 1 1
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Prepping to manage SortBy Clause
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Adjusted Requested Envelope = ReferencedEnvelope[2749970.5 : 2750040.5, 1242959.5 : 1243029.5]
Requested raster dimension = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=70,height=70]
Corresponding raster source region = java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=70,height=70]
Corresponding source Envelope = ReferencedEnvelope[2749970.5 : 2750040.5, 1242959.5 : 1243029.5]
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Loading level 0 with subsampling factors 1 1
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog] - Index Loaded
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Prepping to manage SortBy Clause
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog] - Index Loaded
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been opened. Number open: 1
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Reading from file...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been opened. Number open: 1
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 TRACE [org.geotools.index.quadtree] - QuadTree opened
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,330 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Empty results for 2, skipping read
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to load any granuleDescriptor
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - We got no granules, let's do a dry run with no filters
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog] - Index Loaded
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been opened. Number open: 1
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Reading from file...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Reading from file...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.index.quadtree] - QuadTree opened
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Empty results for 2, skipping read
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to load any granuleDescriptor
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - We got no granules, let's do a dry run with no filters
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.catalog] - Index Loaded
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been opened. Number open: 1
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.index.quadtree] - QuadTree opened
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Empty results for 2, skipping read
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2019-03-08 22:31:10,331 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Creating constant image for area with no data
2019-03-08 22:31:10,332 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Support for alpha on final mosaic
2019-03-08 22:31:10,332 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Applying Raster Symbolizer
--- following part 8x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:10,332 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (GridCoverageFactory)
2019-03-08 22:31:10,332 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (GridCoverageFactory): found implementation Optional.
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:10,334 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,334 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Encoding input image to write out as JPEG.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,334 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Getting a JPEG writer and configuring it.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,335 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Writing out...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,335 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Writing out... Done!
2019-03-08 22:31:10,337 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Reading from file...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,337 TRACE [org.geotools.index.quadtree] - QuadTree opened
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,337 DEBUG [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - Empty results for 2, skipping read
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,337 TRACE [org.geotools.data.shapefile] - IndexFile has been closed. Number open: 0
2019-03-08 22:31:10,337 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Creating constant image for area with no data
2019-03-08 22:31:10,337 DEBUG [org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic] - Support for alpha on final mosaic
2019-03-08 22:31:10,338 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d] - Applying Raster Symbolizer
--- following part 8x ---
2019-03-08 22:31:10,338 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - ENTRY  (GridCoverageFactory)
2019-03-08 22:31:10,338 TRACE [org.geotools.factory] - RETURN (GridCoverageFactory): found implementation Optional.
-------------------------
2019-03-08 22:31:10,339 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -
...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,340 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Encoding input image to write out as JPEG.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,340 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Getting a JPEG writer and configuring it.
2019-03-08 22:31:10,340 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Writing out...
2019-03-08 22:31:10,341 DEBUG [org.geotools.image] - Writing out... Done!
```

Comment: Please add version numbers and the relevant part of the log file on GeoTools debug level.

Comment: I added the versions and the log file part. I removed those parts which were same as in the working `shape://slash` example. If you need more information, I will try to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print custom fonts you have to put them in the mapfish-spring-custom-fonts.xml
https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/blob/74f0bdd74d2c8932c0afae5782a9edd95f1b4678/core/src/main/resources/mapfish-spring-custom-fonts.xml